# How to reference an existing button in your Visual Studio extension .vsct file?

Tags: visual-studio, menu, command, toolbar, visual-studio-extensions

I have created a Visual Studio 2022 extension that has a menu, a submenu and various commands in those menus.  I'm able to add those commands to a toolbar, and the icons I associated with those commands (in my .vsct file) show up as expected (both in the menu and the toolbar).

I want to add an existing command (from a menu in Visual Studio, that I did not create) to one of my submenus, so that it will continue to show up where it does currently, ***plus*** it will show up in my submenu.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it personally, but [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-commands?view=vs-2022) seems to suggest it's possible:

> When you have found the command definition, you can put a copy of the command on another menu or toolbar by creating a CommandPlacement element that has the same guid and id values as the command.

E.g. I found the definition for the `File > Print` command in `ShellCmdDef.vsct`:

```
<Button guid="guidVSStd97" id="cmdidPrint" priority="0x0000" type="Button">
    <Icon guid="guidVsShellIcons" id="cmdidVsShellPrint"/>
    <CommandFlag>AllowClientRole</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>TextChanges</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
        <ButtonText>&amp;Print...</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
</Button>
```

... so I'm assuming you could re-use it with something like this? (untested!)

```
    <CommandPlacements>
        <CommandPlacement guid="guidVSStd97" id="cmdidPrint" priority="0x001" >
            <Parent ... />
        </CommandPlacement>
    </CommandPlacements>
```